# binary search function not searching

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to get my code to work with a binary search function but I can't search anything. Every time I attempt to search for a name from the string I keep getting the "invalid input" from my main function. Please let me know if there's anything else I could do differently! I've been stumped for some time now. Any help will be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int binarySearch(string[], int, string);
void selectionSort(string[], int);
string getValue();

string getValue()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Enter the name you would like to search for: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    return input;
}

int main(){
    const int NUM_NAMES = 20;

    string names[NUM_NAMES] = {"Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Allen, Jim", "Griffin, Jim", "Stamey, Marty", "Rose, Geri", "Taylor, Terri", "Johnson, Jill",
     "Allison, Jeff", "Looney, Joe", "Wolfe, Bill", "James, Jean", "Weaver, Jim", "Pore, Bob", "Rutherford, Greg", "Javens, Renee", "Harrison, Rose", "Setzer, Cathy",
      "Pike, Gordon", "Holland, Beth"
    }; // Insert your code to complete this program

    string value;
    int nameSearch;

    selectionSort(names, NUM_NAMES);

    value = getValue();

    nameSearch = binarySearch(names, NUM_NAMES, value);

    if (nameSearch == -1)
        cout << "invalid input.\n";
    else
        cout << names[nameSearch] << " has been found! #" << nameSearch << ".\n"; 

    return 0;
}

//input to find names in the string

void selectionSort(string array[], int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex;
    string minValue;

    for (int startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        {
            minValue = array[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}

int binarySearch(string array[], int size, string value)
{
    int first = 0,                      // First array element
        last = size - 1,                // Last array element
        middle,                         // Midpoint of search
        position = -1;                  // Position of search value
    bool found = false;                 // Flag

    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;    // Calculate midpoint
        if (array[middle] == value)     // If value is found at mid
        {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }
        else if (array[middle] > value) // If value is in lower half
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            first = middle + 1;         // If value is in upper half
    }
    return position;    
}
```

Comment: Did you try printing out your array after calling `selectionSort`? It doesn't actually work...

Comment: Make a really small program around `selectionSort` that feeds `selectionSort` a set to sort like `{ "C", "B", "A" }` and step through the program with a debugger to watch what happens.

Comment: There is no actual comparison of any sequence data whatsoever in the selection sort implementation. You should consider that an immediate red flag. You can't sort to a particular order without comparing *something*.

Comment: If you want to test your binary search code, feed it a sorted array.  Don't go through your `selectionSort`.  Test one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you print out the `names` array before and after sorting via your `selectionSort` function you can check if it appears to be working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printArray(const std::string[], int);
void selectionSort(std::string[], int);
std::string getValue();
int binarySearch(const std::string[], int, const std::string &);

int main() {
  const int NUM_NAMES = 20;
  std::string names[NUM_NAMES] =
      {"Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Allen, Jim", "Griffin, Jim",
       "Stamey, Marty", "Rose, Geri", "Taylor, Terri", "Johnson, Jill",
       "Allison, Jeff", "Looney, Joe", "Wolfe, Bill", "James, Jean",
       "Weaver, Jim", "Pore, Bob", "Rutherford, Greg", "Javens, Renee",
       "Harrison, Rose", "Setzer, Cathy", "Pike, Gordon", "Holland, Beth"};

  std::cout << "Before Sorting:\n";
  printArray(names, NUM_NAMES);
  selectionSort(names, NUM_NAMES);
  std::cout << "After Sorting:\n";
  printArray(names, NUM_NAMES);

  std::string value = getValue();
  int value_index = binarySearch(names, NUM_NAMES, value);
  if (value_index == -1) {
    std::cout << "Error: Could not find \"" << value << "\" in array.\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << names[value_index] << " has been found at index: "
              << value_index << " \n";
  }

  return 0;
}

void printArray(const std::string array[], int size) {
  if (size < 1) {
    std::cout << "[]";
    return;
  }
  std::cout << '[';
  for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    std::cout << '"' << array[i] << '"' << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << '"' << array[size - 1] << '"';
  std::cout << "]\n";
}

void selectionSort(std::string array[], int size) {
  for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
    int min = j;
    for (int k = j + 1; k < size; k++) {
      if (array[k].compare(array[min]) < 0) {
        min = k;
      }
    }
    std::string temp = array[j];
    array[j] = array[min];
    array[min] = temp;
  }
}

std::string getValue() {
  std::string input;
  std::cout << "Enter the name you would like to search for: ";
  getline(std::cin, input);
  return input;
}

int binarySearch(const std::string array[],
                 int size,
                 const std::string &value) {
  int lo = 0, hi = size - 1;
  while (lo <= hi) {
    int mi = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    if (array[mi] < value) {
      lo = mi + 1;
    } else if (array[mi] > value) {
      hi = mi - 1;
    } else {
      return mi;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Before Sorting:
["Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Allen, Jim", "Griffin, Jim", "Stamey, Marty", "Rose, Geri", "Taylor, Terri", "Johnson, Jill", "Allison, Jeff", "Looney, Joe", "Wolfe, Bill", "James, Jean", "Weaver, Jim", "Pore, Bob", "Rutherford, Greg", "Javens, Renee", "Harrison, Rose", "Setzer, Cathy", "Pike, Gordon", "Holland, Beth"]
After Sorting:
["Allen, Jim", "Allison, Jeff", "Collins, Bill", "Griffin, Jim", "Harrison, Rose", "Holland, Beth", "James, Jean", "Javens, Renee", "Johnson, Jill", "Looney, Joe", "Pike, Gordon", "Pore, Bob", "Rose, Geri", "Rutherford, Greg", "Setzer, Cathy", "Smith, Bart", "Stamey, Marty", "Taylor, Terri", "Weaver, Jim", "Wolfe, Bill"]
Enter the name you would like to search for: Griffin, Jim
Griffin, Jim has been found at index: 3 .
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Before Sorting:
["Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Allen, Jim", "Griffin, Jim", "Stamey, Marty", "Rose, Geri", "Taylor, Terri", "Johnson, Jill", "Allison, Jeff", "Looney, Joe", "Wolfe, Bill", "James, Jean", "Weaver, Jim", "Pore, Bob", "Rutherford, Greg", "Javens, Renee", "Harrison, Rose", "Setzer, Cathy", "Pike, Gordon", "Holland, Beth"]
After Sorting:
["Allen, Jim", "Allison, Jeff", "Collins, Bill", "Griffin, Jim", "Harrison, Rose", "Holland, Beth", "James, Jean", "Javens, Renee", "Johnson, Jill", "Looney, Joe", "Pike, Gordon", "Pore, Bob", "Rose, Geri", "Rutherford, Greg", "Setzer, Cathy", "Smith, Bart", "Stamey, Marty", "Taylor, Terri", "Weaver, Jim", "Wolfe, Bill"]
Enter the name you would like to search for: sdgfdsfgsdfg
Error: Could not find "sdgfdsfgsdfg" in array.
```